# Cannot print multiple pages with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created an app with AngularJS which has several cards that I want to print. But it only prints the initial view (with scroll bar) instead of multiple pages.

I have tried using window.print(), a custom element using innnerHtml and this angular print directive: [link](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2014/08/09/building-a-simple-angularjs-print-directive/)

I have a print stylesheet which displays the rest of the cards in the ng-repeat that aren't shown at the time and includes *overflow:visible* and *height:auto* for any parent elements.

I feel like I'm missing something simple.

See:

[image]

Comment: Don't you think other than giving printing command through `window.print()` rest of the functionality become out of scope for `JS` and controlled by native printing console??

Comment: Yes but I'm not sure what else to do

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation in my app (angularjs+ MVC+ WEBAPI) where I was having issues in printing as well. I was able to print over Firefox and IE but not on Chrome. It may be something because of how Chrome, constructs the dom.

So what I did was that I extracted the html in a method using jquery and opened it up in a new tab, disabled scripting and then opened window.print() and it worked for me.

Hope the same works for you